# Pervasive dval stores dates as integer in days from 01/01/0001. I need a function to convert it for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pervasive

I need help. Pervasive DB stored dates in days. For example 719311 would be the amount of days from 01/01/0001 to May 28 1970. So May 28 1970 is the date represented in pervasive when looking at 719311.

Comment: Your question is tagged "sql-server" which implies Microsoft SQL Server. Please remove that tag and use "database" or something instead

Comment: I need this for sql server. The data comes into sql and needed to be stored as an actual date not an integer representing days.

Comment: I misunderstood what pervasive was, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
select datediff(day,'0001-01-01','1753-01-01') + 2

select 719311 - 639907 -- sql 

select dateadd(day,79404,'1753-01-01')
```

`dateadd()` function cannot work with a date older than '1753-01-01', so you need the 719311 days minus the 639907 days. The difference you can than plug into the `dateadd()` function.

You should get this `1970-05-28 00:00:00.000`

Comment: This worked. Just used it inline with the data being imported like DATEADD(DAY,COLUMNNAME - 639907,'1753-01-01') and the dates showed up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Servers `dateadd` feature for this.  However the values in Pervasive are much too large to add to the base date of 0 (1900-01-01).

To work around that I used the known integer/date provided and calculated the delta between 0001-01-01 and 1900-01-01 - which is 693597.  This value is static, and can be subtracted from each Pervasive value and used in the `dateadd`.  The result can then be added to 1900-01-01.

```
-- GET BASE DATE OF 0
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,0)

-- CALCULATE DIFF FROM 0 TO A KNOWN DATE...
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,0,'1970-05-28')

--SUBTRACT ABOVE DIFF FROM KNOWN INTEGER FOR SAID DATE... THIS IS OUR DELTA
SELECT 719311-25714

-- ADD THE INTEGER OF SAID DATE, MINUS THE ABOVE DELTA TO 0 TO CONFIRM WE GET THE KNOWN DATE.
SELECT DATEADD(DD,719311-693597,0)

-- USING VARIABLES, LEAVE @DELTA AS A STATIC VALUE, JUST UPDATE @PERVASIVE
DECLARE @PERVASIVE INT, @DELTA INT
SET @PERVASIVE=719312

SET @DELTA=693597
SELECT DATEADD(DD,@PERVASIVE-@DELTA,0)
```

Comment: I would recommend using `day` instead of `dd`. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: I'm not Aaron, @AaronBertrand is the author of that article.

Comment: Thank you for that @SqlZim!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is add days to a `date` datatype.

When I add `719311` days to `'0001-01-01'` I get `'1970-05-30'`
To get `'1970-05-28'` I have to remove 2 of those days.

```
select dateadd(day,719311-2,convert(date,'00010101'))
```

returns `'1970-05-28'`